# Mono and WebClient

Tags: monodevelop

I have a weird problem

I develop a rest client on MonoDevelop on Linux.

The code is really simple :

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var wc = new WebClient();


        Console.WriteLine(wc.DownloadString("https://cex.io/api/ticker/BTC/USD"));
    }
```

When I execute this code in MonoDevelop, I have theoutput everything is fine.

But When I execute it via command line : mono Test.exe

I get the following error :

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.Net.WebException: Error: SecureChannelFailure (The authentication or decryption has failed.) ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: The authentication or decryption has failed.
>     at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.EndReceiveRecord (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00040] in <1d0bb82c94e7435eb09324cf5ef20e36>:0 
>     at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.SafeEndReceiveRecord (System.IAsyncResult ar, System.Boolean ignoreEmpty) [0x00000] in <1d0bb82c94e7435eb09324cf5ef20e36>:0 
>     at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.NegotiateAsyncWorker (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00071] in <1d0bb82c94e7435eb09324cf5ef20e36>:0 
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.EndNegotiateHandshake (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x0003b] in <1d0bb82c94e7435eb09324cf5ef20e36>:0 
>     at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.AsyncHandshakeCallback (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0000c] in <1d0bb82c94e7435eb09324cf5ef20e36>:0 
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.EndRead (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00057] in <1d0bb82c94e7435eb09324cf5ef20e36>:0 
>     at Mono.Net.Security.Private.LegacySslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00011] in :0 
>     at Mono.Net.Security.Private.LegacySslStream.AuthenticateAsClient (System.String targetHost, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, System.Boolean checkCertificateRevocation) [0x0000e] in :0 
>     at Mono.Net.Security.MonoTlsStream.CreateStream (System.Byte[] buffer) [0x00044] in :0 
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal (System.Uri address, System.Net.WebRequest& request) [0x0008a] in :0 
>     at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString (System.Uri address) [0x00027] in :0 
>     at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString (System.String address) [0x00019] in :0 
>     at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Net.WebClient:DownloadString (string)
>     at test.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x0002e] in <68578489534a4def9ee53ede9b043d48>:0 
>   [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.Net.WebException: Error: SecureChannelFailure (The authentication or decryption has failed.) ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: The authentication or decryption has failed.
>     at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.EndReceiveRecord (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00040] in <1d0bb82c94e7435eb09324cf5ef20e36>:0 
>     at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.SafeEndReceiveRecord (System.IAsyncResult ar, System.Boolean ignoreEmpty) [0x00000] in <1d0bb82c94e7435eb09324cf5ef20e36>:0 
>     at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.NegotiateAsyncWorker (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00071] in <1d0bb82c94e7435eb09324cf5ef20e36>:0 
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.EndNegotiateHandshake (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x0003b] in <1d0bb82c94e7435eb09324cf5ef20e36>:0 
>     at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.AsyncHandshakeCallback (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0000c] in <1d0bb82c94e7435eb09324cf5ef20e36>:0 
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.EndRead (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00057] in <1d0bb82c94e7435eb09324cf5ef20e36>:0 
>     at Mono.Net.Security.Private.LegacySslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00011] in :0 
>     at Mono.Net.Security.Private.LegacySslStream.AuthenticateAsClient (System.String targetHost, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, System.Boolean checkCertificateRevocation) [0x0000e] in :0 
>     at Mono.Net.Security.MonoTlsStream.CreateStream (System.Byte[] buffer) [0x00044] in :0 
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal (System.Uri address, System.Net.WebRequest& request) [0x0008a] in :0 
>     at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString (System.Uri address) [0x00027] in :0 
>     at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString (System.String address) [0x00019] in :0 
>     at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Net.WebClient:DownloadString (string)
>     at test.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x0002e] in <68578489534a4def9ee53ede9b043d48>:0

I really don't understand why the differents behavior, the only thing I can see is that MonoDevelop is opened via flatpak, but I don't know what .NET config it is used

I have already tested the solutions [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/10405/the-authentication-or-decryption-has-failed-in-the-web-request) without success. And I suppose it is a config issue because it works with monodevelop

thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have finally found

I have to build Mono from the official repository